# How to download PERSON type column details from SharePoint list using VBA?

Tags: vba, sharepoint

SharePoint.  VBA

I'm downloading SharePoint list using this code:

```
Set sourceWb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=sharePointFilePath, ReadOnly:=True)
Set sourceWs = sourceWb.Worksheets(worksheetName)
Set destWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(destWsName)
destWs.Cells.ClearContents
sourceWs.Cells.Copy destWs.Cells
```

It works well. However, there is one columns, type `person` that has a name of associate in the SharePoint List. When I hover over this column, it shows a pop up window with all associate details including email. I want that downloaded too.

Currently my code only downloads the plain first and last name. How can i download all the details visible upon column hover over pop up, such as email, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can try and "[work with folders and files with REST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest)".
The goal would be to fetch the data, then parse the results in VBA to retrieve the required information like the email.

From your VBA editor, import (<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>, `File > Import File`):

- [`JsonConverter.bas`](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas) from [`VBA-tools/VBA-JSON`](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON)
- [`WebHelpers.bas`](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Web/blob/master/src/WebHelpers.bas) from [`VBA-tools/VBA-Web`](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Web)

And test out:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub DownloadSharePointList()

    ' Replace these variables with your values
    Dim siteUrl As String: siteUrl = "https://your_domain.sharepoint.com/sites/yoursite/"
    Dim listName As String: listName = "YourListName"
    Dim destWsName As String: destWsName = "Sheet1"
    Dim personFieldName As String: personFieldName = "PersonColumnName"

    Dim destWs As Worksheet
    Set destWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(destWsName)
    destWs.Cells.ClearContents
    
    ' Query SharePoint REST API
    Dim objHTTP As Object
    Dim response As String
    Dim json As Object
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
    
    With objHTTP
        .Open "GET", siteUrl & "_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" & listName & "')/items?$expand=" & personFieldName & "/EMail", False
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json;odata=verbose"
        .setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose"
        .send
        response = .responseText
    End With
    
    ' Parse JSON response
    Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(response)
    
    ' Write headers
    Dim headers() As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1
    headers = Array("Title", personFieldName & "_Name", personFieldName & "_EMail")
    For i = LBound(headers) To UBound(headers)
        destWs.Cells(1, i).Value = headers(i)
    Next i
    
    ' Write data
    Dim item As Variant
    Dim row As Integer
    row = 2
    For Each item In json("d")("results")
        destWs.Cells(row, 1).Value = item("Title")
        destWs.Cells(row, 2).Value = item(personFieldName)("Title")
        destWs.Cells(row, 3).Value = item(personFieldName)("EMail")
        row = row + 1
    Next item

End Sub
```